# How to determine asymptotes?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, asymptotics

In general do we say that:

1. If, for some given $x$, we get $y = 0/0$, it's a removable discontinuity.
2. If, for some given $x$, we get $y = a/0$ for $a \neq 0$, it's a vertical asymptote at that $x$.
3. If, for $x \to \infty$, we get $y = c$, then there is a horizontal asymptote at $y=c$.

Would you say this is correct so far? Am I missing anything?

Comment: your #1 is oversimple. Consider $\sin(x)/x^2$.

Comment: @Lubin How about a function $f(x)$ that involves some function $g(x)/g(x)$ where $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$ in the domain.

Comment: By "we get" do you mean to let $x \to c$ (and then also $y=f(x)$ and numerators are limits of $y$ as $x \to c$)?

Comment: @coffeemath I don't know, I just want to understand how to determine where asymptotes are and I'm trying to generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1 is not true in general, for point 2 the case is $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ with $h(x_0)=0$ and $g(x_0)\neq 0$ and x_0 cluster point, point 3 are correct.

Remember also the case for **oblique asymptotes**

- $y=mx+n$ with $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$.

with

$$m=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

and

$$n=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} (f(x)-mx)$$

when both limit exist.

Answer (score 1):

For $(1)$ ,$0/0$ is not always a removable discontinuity.

For $(3)$ , you may add $x\to -\infty $ as well.

I do not see any other issues.

Comment: In total agreement, except that I insist that a function $f$ may only be said to be continuous or discontinuous *at a point where $f$ is defined*. The terminology that I would urge on all is “removable singularity”.